# Could Vた-form be an adjective?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

In the following sentence:

> 割れた彗星の一部は隕石となって、日本に落下。

Though it sounds strange and amateurish, I see 割れた as an adjective for 彗星. So what is the grammatical role of 割れた in this sentence? and if it is the case that somehow alike to the way past participle is used as an adjective in the English language, in the Japanese language た-form could be also used as an adjective?

Comment: I would translate it as a past participle adjective, 'part of the broken comet...' Is it not generally taught that you can do this with Japanese relative clauses?

Comment: Why do you think it sounds strange and amateurish?

Comment: @VeryCommonName So I should work on "relative clauses", thanks

Comment: @AeonAkechi Because it does not make any sense in the category of i-adjective and na-adjective, but again it has a strong sense of adjective

Comment: @Quince Blossom If you did not know that you can effectively translate a Japanese relative clause as a past participle then perhaps, yes, you should work on them.

Comment: @QuinceBlossom Maybe it sounds less like an adjective if you read it as "comet that broke" rather than "broken comet". But relative clauses 'describe' the noun they modify, just like an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could Vた-form be an adjective?

No, the past tense form doesn't change the nature of the word, it's still a verb even in the past tense.

Although it is most of the time translated in English as an adjective, the right way to understand it in Japanese is as below:

> 割れた彗星 : the comet that cracked